# What exactly is going on under the hood of WHERE clause in SQL when filtering based on two columns inequality

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

Let's assume we have a following table:

In short, there are unique ids in col1 and some non-unique corresponding values in col2.
Say we want to find the rows where col2 values are not uniquely defined.
e.g. in the following example such rows are 1 and 4.

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "a" |
| 2 | "b" |
| 3 | "c" |
| 4 | "a" |

So I found the following cryptic-looking (for me) code that does the job (test is the name of the table above):

```
SELECT *
FROM test a
WHERE col2 IN (SELECT col2 FROM test b WHERE b.col1 <> a.col1);
```

Sure, one way to do the task is to group by col2 and filter out those values that have count(col1) equal 1, but what does concern me is not the task at hand, but rather how does the WHERE clause in this context work.

I am aware of how tables are explicitly joined with JOINs, and I also understand the common use of WHERE clause like `WHERE somecol != value`. Yet, the way `WHERE somecol != othercol` work in this context is beyond me.

Could someone give me a clue of how does the code above work?
Maybe the question is stupid, sorry if that is the case.
Thanks!

edit:
[Execution analysis here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E19ZD.png)

Comment: You tagged multiple RDBMS. If your query relates to one of them then please edit that one back in but don't tag multiple.

Comment: Database engines are quite different under the hood. You can't really compare the index-based MySQL engine with the heap-based Oracle and PostgreSQL engines. Besides, their repertoire of operations are quite limited (MySQL) or extensive (Oracle). Apart from that, their optimizers are substantially different. Please select a single engine and provide the execution plan.

Comment: Your query doesn't work as you have two different tables `test` and `test1`.

Comment: @MT0 thanks for pointing out the typo, but it is not the cause of the misunderstanding. Edited the post.

Comment: @TheImpaler thanks for information! Could you please suggest a resource where to read more about db engines?

Comment: @MT0 left just postgresql. The reason I tagged multiple is because the query works the same way in all of them. Didn't know it is not a good practice on stackoverflow.

Comment: Jironymo Jirolamus. No the different databases **do not** work the same way. That is what @TheImpaler is saying. Given the same data the same query will  produce the same results, provided the syntax is correct in each. That does not mean they work the same way *under the hood*. In fact on one database a query works one way, but given different data volumes, the same query on the same database may work differently under the hood.

Comment: @Belayer, understood, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of indexes, such a `where` clause is generally going to be implemented as a nested loop construct.

That is, for each row in the outer query, the engine is going to run the inner query.  For each row, it will compare `col1`.  And when these are not equal, it will check if `col2` is the same in the outer query.

Engines do have a variety of algorithms so this is not guaranteed.  However, non-equality conditions are harder to optimize and less frequent.

That said, there are much more efficient ways to express the query.  For instance, you can use window functions.  I believe this is the same logic -- assuming the values in the columns are not `NULL`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(col1) over (partition by col2) as min_col1,
             max(col1) over (partition by col2) as max_col1
      from test t
     ) t
where min_col1 <> max_col1;
```

Comment: Thanks for a profound and easy to follow explanation!